# How do I stop repeated execution of alert() inside an if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.credentials input');

function checkCredentials(){
    inputs.forEach(function(input){


       if(input.value=="" && !alert('please enter a valid card number')){
          
         alert('please enter a valid card number'); 
    
       }

        else{        
         alert("payment successful");
       
       }
       
    })
}
```

```html
    <div class="card-container">
          
          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="visa.png">
          </div><!-- card img -->

          <div class="credentials">
            
            <input type="text" name="1">
            <input type="text" name="2">
            <input type="text" name="3">
            <input type="text" name="4">

            <input type="text" name="5" class="fifth-input">
            <input type="text" name="6">
            <input type="text" name="7">
            <input type="text" name="8">

            <input type="text" name="9" class="ninth-input">
            <input type="text" name="10">
            <input type="text" name="11">
            <input type="text" name="12">

            <input type="text" name="13" class="thirteenth-input">
            <input type="text" name="14">
            <input type="text" name="15">
            <input type="text" name="16">

          </div><!-- credentials -->

          <div class="btn">
            <button onclick="checkCredentials();">Click to Proceed</button>
          </div><!-- btn -->    
    </div><!-- card container -->
```

I have a 16 inputs each input field with maximum one digits, what I want is,  On click of a button
-If any of the input field is empty the an alert box saying 'please enter a valid card number must display' once and page be reloaded.
-else an alert box saying 'payment successful' displayed once and page reloaded.

Comment: Use a regular loop instead of `forEach` and cancel it with a `break` statement when you altered once.

Comment: Reloading a page if only _one_ of sixteen inputs is empty will be infuriating to the user.

Comment: Seriously, 16 text fields for 1 card number?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.credentials input');
let numberVar;
function checkCredentials(){
    numberVar = 0;
    inputs.forEach(function(input){
       if(input.value=="" && numberVar++ < 1){ 
         alert('please enter a valid card number');
       }else{        
         alert("payment successful");
       }    
    })
}
```

But if you need to go through all the inputs and show which value is not filled, then you need a different approach. And also the expression needs to be rewritten in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the Array for the given criteria and check if the Array is empty or not.
I would also suggest to use input Parameters for functions and not use global Variables =)

Example:

```js
function checkCredentials(inputs){
        const containsEmptyInputs = inputs.filter(i => i == "").length > 0;
        const message = containsEmptyInputs ? 'please enter a valid card number' : 'payment successful';
        alert(message);
}
```